# RROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using this function to upload the file

```
 async uploadFile(file)
  {  
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
     this.file=`<a href='${this.FileName}' target=_blank'>File</a>`; 
     this.send(); 
     resolve(this.FileName);
```

Calling `this.send` but getting this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading angular` at `this.send()` line.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function instead of function expression so that upload call back `this` will point to parent scope.

```
 bucket.upload(params, (err, data)=> { 
  .......
 });
```